# Xamarin can not deploy to iPhone as there is no Run option

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator

My Xamarin project can build, but not deploy out to my iPhone as there is no Run option:

[image]

How can this be alleviated?

Comment: As far as I am aware, both Debug | iPhone & Release | iPhone will build to your device, assuming that you have created the appropriate provisioning profiles and certificates through apples developer website.

Comment: There was no provisioning file,  once created it could deploy